# Driving a 125cc motorcycle in the UK with French licence

Tags: uk, driving-licenses, motorcycles

I have imported a 125cc motorcycle from France to the UK, and registered and insured it there.

I have a French 125cc licence ("permis A1"), which is a car driving licence ("permis B") + a one-day motorcycling training.

Am I allowed to drive it in the UK with this license only? Or do I need to get another one?

Comment: Is this a full licence for your motorcycle?  That is, could you lawfully drive that bike, in France, on your current licence, indefinitely?

Comment: In France I can drive with it forever, yes

Comment: Since you say you've imported the bike, this question might strictly belong on the sister site https://expatriates.stackexchange.com . If you want it migrated, you can click on the flag icon and write a custom message to the moderators.

Comment: I do not feel this is an expat question, it is a 'can I travel with this vehicle and these licenses' question.

Comment: Note that you might need to switch the headlight to prevent blinding of other drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is Yes. All EU member states use standardised driving licences, at least for the categories with capital letters.

The UK restrictions on an A1 licence are

- You can drive light motorbikes with:

  - an engine size up to 125cc
  - a power output of up to 11kW
  - a power to weight ratio not more than 0.1kW/kg
- This category also includes motor tricycles with power output up to 15kW.

If your moving to the UK, then you'll need to insure and register at    a UK address. (Registering is different in Northern Ireland, to the rest of the UK). If it is over 3 years old, you will also need to put it through an annual test, the MOT.

You will not need to take a UK test, at least until Brexit.

[https://www.gov.uk/driving-licence-categories]